# How to read to read Ethereum block transaction: data field containing bytes[] field

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, etherscan

Is it possible to decode the input data of something like `multicall(uint256 deadline, bytes[] data)` by looking at the Ethereum block transaction `data` field?

A given ethereum transaction might contain a data field such as:

```
{
    "hash":"0x688c0f7e7ad5c59e4c3e24199e8e56753b95960324e3bb41da210eb0416e581d",
    "nonce":"0x73",
    "blockHash":"0x33fbe975a5a9c6a399c55f1bcb8130cd1d0c560722483dcd72d964020f156f7d",
    "blockNumber":"0xdc0ba9",
    "transactionIndex":"0xde",
    "from":"0xfcf9c19841cd8c6cd7114e638b02e62189a89601",
    "to":"0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45",
    "value":"0x0",
    "gasPrice":"0x4190ab000",
    "gas":"0x6621f",
    "data":"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",
    "input":"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",
    "type":"0x0",
    "v":"0x26",
    "s":"0x3397f6969aec9a7d1c168765985d9ff51d9b1bb4a84126ce561e1793bcc82af7",
    "r":"0xd692324d08b4ed25a2b7a37cc247b4f879d0e3bcb3d851fdc087f3ad40579edb"
}
```

According to this [etherscan record](https://etherscan.io/address/0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45#code), the above block is a transaction sent to [Uniswap V3: Router 2](https://etherscan.io/address/0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45#code). I want to decode the `data` field. Using the [Ethereum ABI Spec](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html), the contract's ABI can be used to find get the hash of all the functions in the smart contract. Comparing the first eight characters in the Keccak-256 hash of the function `multicall(uint256,bytes[])`, `5ae401dc`, to the beginning of the `data` field above, identifies the function call.

However, at this point I cannot tell what the `bytes[]` array above refers to, and so cannot decode the rest of the `data` field. It seems like the only way to really decode this call is to comb through the uniswap source code to map the remaining bytes into something more human readable.

But somehow etherscan.io manages to show us that this transaction decodes to:
[image]

Am I missing something, or is the only way to arrive at the list of transfers above to go through the contract data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Etherscan token transfer list comes from event logs generated by the transaction. Not directly from the `data` field.

The multicall argument only specifies a list of addresses to perform internal transactions to, and their data fields.

You can see the list of event logs in the transaction receipt. For example using [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/):

```
const TRANSFER_EVENT_SIGNATURE = web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)");
const txHash = "0x688c0f7e7ad5c59e4c3e24199e8e56753b95960324e3bb41da210eb0416e581d";
const txReceipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
for (let log of txReceipt.logs) {
    if (log.topics[0] == TRANSFER_EVENT_SIGNATURE) {
        // This is an event log of the Transfer() event
        console.log(log);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, so the logs are not stored on the blockchain, but in the receipts which can be generated from the blockchain data historically by archive nodes? And if I wanted that data locally I'd have to run an archive node, correct?

Comment: @brasides The logs **are** stored in the blockchain as part of the transaction receipts. Which are part of the raw block generated by miners and broadcasted to the network each time a new block is mined... Full nodes keep only some number of old blocks (the actual number depends on the config of each node instance), so if you want to retrieve historical data, you might need an archive node.